# voicexml output of the external grammar and refill the field element

Tags: field, voicexml

I would like, that if the user says "help" that the following field doesn't get filled, and that the user gets all possible options.

```
<form id="test">    
    <field name="var1">


<prompt bargein="true" bargeintype="hotword" >say xy </prompt>

<grammar src = "grammar.grxml" type="application/srgs+xml"  />



    <filled>
    <assign name="myProdukt" expr="var1" />
    you said <value expr="myProdukt"/>
    </filled>

</field>
```

(let's say in the external grammar is "p1", "p2" and "p3", the user says "help", and the systems says "p1","p2","p3" and the user can choose again - therefore the word "help" has to be in the external grammar as well, doesn't it?)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the active grammar must contain a "help" utterance which returns the value 'help'.   You then catch the event with a `help` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.xsd">
    <form id="test">    
        <field name="var1">
            <prompt bargein="true" bargeintype="hotword" >say xy </prompt>
            <grammar src = "grammar.grxml" type="application/srgs+xml"  />
            <filled>
                <assign name="myProdukt" expr="var1" />
                you said <value expr="myProdukt"/>
            </filled>
            <help>
                To choose a product, say, 
                <!-- whatever the product choices are -->
                frobinator, submarine, curling iron, .. 
                <reprompt/>
            </help>
        </field>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

Alternatively, following the [*DRY principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), this effect can be done *globally* for your application with using an **application root document**  containing a `link` element.   In the example `app-root.vxml` document below, there is a `link`binding a global grammar "help" utterance to the `help` event :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<vxml version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml">
   <link event="help">
      <grammar mode="voice" root="root_rule" tag-format="semantics/1.0"
               type="application/srgs+xml" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US">
            <rule id="root_rule" scope="public">
                  <one-of>
                        <item weight="1.0">
                              help
                        </item>
                  </one-of>
            </rule>
      </grammar>
   </link>
</vxml>
```

This grammar will be active everywhere -- effectively merged with each active field grammar. If you need more information about application root documents, the section of the VoiceXML specification [*Executing a Multi-Document Application*](http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml1.5.2) explains.  Also see [*Handling Events*](https://studio.tellme.com/vxml2/ovw/events.html) from the **Tellme Studio** documentation

Then, in pages of your application, make reference to the application root document via the `application` attribute of the `vxml` element and speak appropriately in a `help` catch block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/vxml http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/vxml.xsd"
    application="app-root.vxml">
    <form id="test">    
        <field name="var1">
            <prompt bargein="true" bargeintype="hotword" >say xy </prompt>
            <grammar src = "grammar.grxml" type="application/srgs+xml"  />
            <filled>
                <assign name="myProdukt" expr="var1" />
                you said <value expr="myProdukt"/>
            </filled>
            <help>
                To choose a product, say, 
                <!-- whatever the product choices are -->
                frobinator, submarine, curling iron, .. 
                <reprompt/>
            </help>
        </field>
    </form>
</vxml>
```

You could, of course, put the `link` code in the same page as your form, but it is likely you will want `help` active for every field of your application unless there is collision with something in a particular field's grammar.